# Spring Data Rest Projection links are different if referenced indirectly

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring Data Rest project that has some relationships, but I'm finding the HATEOAS links are different depending if a projection is directly called rather than being referenced via another projection.

I'm doing this so that I can load a skeleton structure for fast initial load, then querying entities directly when I need more details. For example, skipping the entities directly, if a projection is set up as:

```
@Projection(name="userDetails")
public Interface UserProjection {
    String getName();
    List<RoomProjection> getRooms();
}

@Projection(name="RoomDetails")
public Interface RoomProjection {
    String getName();
    List<ComputerProjection> getComputers();
}

@Projection(name="ComputerDetails")
public Interface ComputerProjection {
    String getName();
}
```

The response from looking up the `GET /users?projection=userDetails` gives us:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "users": [
            {
                "name": "User One",
                "rooms": [
                    {
                        "name": "Room One",
                        "computers": [
                            {
                                "name": "Computer One",
                                "_links": {
                                    "self": {
                                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/computers/1{?projection}",
                                        "templated": true
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "_links": {
                            "self": {
                                "href": "http://localhost:8080/rooms/1{?projection}",
                                "templated": true
                            },
                            "computers": {
                                "href": "http://localhost:8080/rooms/1/computers"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/users/1"
                    },
                    "user": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/users/1{?projection}",
                        "templated": true
                    },
                    "rooms": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/users/1/rooms"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see the self link for the rooms and computers gets the projection argument and lose the self referencing link, that isn't present in the users. But unless I drill down via the embedded projections I don't appear to be able to provide a lightweight overview.

Is there a simple way of having the self links stay consistent and not include the projection?